# Is a bounty protection for a question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have been using Stack Overflow quite heavily for last couple of years as I journey into coding. I use it not only to find answers to issues, but also to ask a few questions of my own and to attempt to fix others' issues to give myself a bit of real world practice.

Lately I find my questions are probably very broad and admittedly quite poor and harder to articulate as I venture down the rabbit hole.

The bounty rules state that I have approximately 2 days before I can bounty my question, providing it's not closed: once the bounty is in place, however, it's protected against being closed.

On the same topic I also find when I bounty questions that are likely to gain the tumbleweed badge, I find a large majority of the answers are very detailed and the people are extremely helpful and much more personable.

So, why can't I bounty on day one?

Comment: Recently, I flagged a blatantly off-topic and bounty-protected question. Took a couple of days, but there was time for it to be closed by a mod and the bounty refunded (if I got the facts right).

Comment: Bountied questions are not protected, a moderator can still be flagged to close it.

Comment: I've tagged many bountied questions as being off-topic and protected by bounty from normal closure. Moderators can cancel the bounty, making the question eligible for closure, or simply close it themselves as off-topic. I would not hesitate to also flag extremely low quality questions such as you're describing for that reason as well. (Don't forget that bounty protected questions are not immune from being downvoted like any other question, and they cost the poster the usual amount of rep in addition to the bounty they will give up.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your first question: Yes; you are protected from closure by the community, but you can still be downvoted.

To answer your second, I don't know for sure (perhaps Shog can explain), but I see a couple benefits:

- You don't pay for exposure you don't need, if the question is popular
- You can't protect a *really* bad question before the community has a chance to deal with it.

#### Related:

- [Why can't I just offer a bounty for a question right off the bat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat)
- [Reduce time in which a user can attach a bounty to a Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13109/reduce-time-in-which-a-user-can-attach-a-bounty-to-a-question)
- [Should the bounty waiting period be reduced to 24 hours?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89678/should-the-bounty-waiting-period-be-reduced-to-24-hours)

Comment: Those are both good reasons. There are others: we don't want to encourage "mandatory" bounties and there are a number of forms of abuse that become considerably easier if you don't have to wait.

Comment: @Shog9: Should flags on bountied questions get preferential treatment, so if a question which slipped through the cracks thus gets attention, it will be handled expeditiously? Or is that already happening?

Comment: "[C]an't protect a really bad question before the community has a chance to deal with it?" Hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha... man.... * wiping tears * Gosh, I guess every time I raised a custom flag on a blatantly "give me a tool/link/resource/tutorial", or a Shark vs Gorilla question that had a bounty on it I was hallucinating.

Comment: @Louis I never said it got *everything*, but if the time restriction was removed, you could immediately bounty it and get a whole *week* of terrible question protection. At least this way, the community has two days to moderate it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET True.

Comment: Why, @Deduplicator? The only thing the question is "protected" from is closing, and that is temporary at best - voting, editing, discussion are all still available. If the question is causing enough problems to warrant moderation attention, they'll get to it - but unless it's spam, blatantly-offensive, or devolving into heated arguments, there's rarely a need to rush.