# closing bounty questions

Tags: discussion, bounty, moderation

So I had [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26901383/1860929) a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26753281/1860929) here with an open [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26753281/revisions) on it, and three days in, the question has been closed today as too broad by a moderator.

Because of the moderator close vote, the bounty from it has been removed and [credited back](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80353/kim-stacks?tab=reputation&sort=post) to the OP's account. Since the question has been closed, no additional bounties can be awarded on it either

A big part of the motivation for attempting to answer a bounty question is that bounty itself - it poses the question as harder to solve than your other regular questions - it offers both a good challenge, and a good reward. For 
[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26901383/1860929) in this instance, I did happen to input close to an hour coming up with what I thought would be a working approach, while discarding those that wouldn't work.

Now in this particular instance, I would have voted for too broad myself it was available to me. In fact, that was [the starting line of my initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26901383/1).

So, When normal users with privileges can't close vote a bounty question, why can a moderator do it in the bounty period? And if mods can, why isn't a normal user like me allowed to flag the post similarly?

Comment: Mods can do it so *terrible* content (and spam) can be closed/removed even under the "protection". In a lot of cases; answering a closeable question becomes a case of "Answerer beware".

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Agree to that, but can't understand why only mods can do it. If I try casting a close vote on a bounty question, I get `This question has an open bounty and can't be closed` message in red.

Comment: Because its "protected" (that part is a pretty recent duplicate). I'll see if I can find the link.

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/very-broad-question-but-with-a-bounty-what-to-do and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275852/is-a-bounty-protection-for-a-question

Comment: @BradleyDotNET +1. So can only the mods with the diamonds do that, or >20k rep users as well, or tag golden badges as well?

Comment: To my knowledge; diamond mods only

Comment: Only diamond mods can close a question *while* it has a bounty on it, but the votes that were cast *before* the bounty was placed remain. So you may see, like in the case at hand here, a vote from an underling, plus a vote from a diamond mod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refunding a bounty is a big deal.  It creates a lot of potentials for abuses, either by people trying to get their own bounty points back, possibly even after already getting a lot of the valuable attention, trying to prevent others from getting a deserved bounty, trying to prevent a bounty from being auto-awarded, etc.

While there are certainly lots of problems with refunding bounties, there are also exceptional cases where it needs to be done.  Because these cases are both unusual and exceptional, often controversial, potentially complex, etc. it simply makes sense to limit handling these cases to moderators.  Too many problems would be created if regular users could do this, and too many problems wouldn't be able to be solved if moderators couldn't do it.

Comment: so what should we do when we find an off-topic question if it has a bounty?

Comment: @TheFool You flag it for moderator attention explaining that the question has a bounty but needs to be closed (and explain why it needs to be closed).